# Creating a non SPA application, where the side chat bar remains static and does not refresh

Tags: spring-boot

I am creating a social dashboard which has a side chat bar. i am using Springboot to render pure HTML pages with JQuery and Ajax calls. I want to know is it possible to have the side chat menu remain fixed while performing view controller changes since it is not a SPA (Single page application) like Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible. You can use different techniques like long polling or websocket (preferable) to achieve this usecase. As far as presentation goes, Jquery will help you to achieve this.